# i686-elf-gcc not creating output file (kernel.o)

Tags: gcc, operating-system, kernel

I was following the osdev barebones tutorial and successfully created boot.o and linker.ld, but ran into a problem when the i686-elf-gcc compiler didn't create the kernel.o file. It gave no errors. This is what I ran to compile it:

```
i686-elf-gcc -c kernel.c -o kernel.o -std=gnu99 -ffreestanding -O2 -Wall -Wextra
```

But no matter how many times I do it, there's still no kernel.o!

Comment: Add `-v` after `i686-elf-gcc` to understand what is going on and put the `-c kernel.c -o kernel.o` after all other arguments. Consider learning and using [make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)

Comment: I'll try, but why would i need to change the arguments if the command was copied from a tutorial that seems to work for everyone else? By the way, do i need to install gcc too for it to work?